# How to preserve Apache Tomcat7 configuration files when reinstalling application

Tags: apache, tomcat, configuration

I am using Apache Tomcat7 for one of my projects and in order to store some container specific configuration, I am using an XML file under the /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/ directory (in linux). For example /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/my-app.xml if the app in question is called my-app.

When I reinstall (update) the application, the afore mentioned file, seems to be deleted during the installation process. Is there any way to preserve this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! Have done this mistake quite some time.

There are several conditions (like changing the war file, deleting the webapp or replacing it with new content) under which tomcat will undeploy the context including removing the context file.

You should stop your server before making any changes like changing your war file. If you try to edit or move the deployed war file the corresponding configuration in `conf/Catalina/localhost/` will get deleted.

If you do not wish this behavior you can edit the `server.xml` file located in `conf/` directory.

Change

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
```

and make `autoDeploy="false"`

For more details you can refer to [Apache Tomcat Configuration Reference](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/host.html#Automatic%20Application%20Deployment)